# http client - how can I extract http response containing custom header fields?

Tags: javascript, http, client, response

My web server send http response with custom header fields if some condition was satisfied.

And I want client to detect this response. 
So In my thinking,.. I need to capture all response and check the header..

Capturing all response is possible on Javascript?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript

Comment: What do you mean by `capture all responses`? There will always a response for each successful request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)

Comment: @Lewis I mean that client need to inspect all responses to find some response containing custom header fields.. And I want to know how can I implement it.

Comment: Then there is no simpler way than catching each individual response returned from server and check for the proper headers.